# How to convert System.__ComObject to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, qlikview, comobject

```
case 6: //text
    QVObject.GetSheet().Activate();
    ReportControl.QVApp.WaitForIdle();
    if (objectName == "TX01")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have found my fullname again");
        //tamp_val = QVObject.CopyTextToClipboard(); // copy text field in global object tamp_val

        Console.WriteLine("GetRelevantSelection my object type" + QVObject.GetRelevantSelections());

        Console.WriteLine("The type of my object is :" + QVObject.GetType());
    }
```

`QVObject.GetType()` returns a `System.__ComObject`. How to save this result as a `string`?

Comment: have you tried `.ToString()` ?

Comment: @ChaimEliyah That's not going to make the slightest bit of difference. `.ToString()` is getting called already. Just not on a useful object.

Comment: I tried To.string()... does not work

Comment: What are `QVApp` and `QVObject`?

Comment: What do you expect `GetType` to return?

Comment: GetRelevantSelection my object typeSystem.Object[]
The type of my object is :System.__ComObject

Comment: I am pulling charts from Qlik View software.

Comment: I have a sheet of charts QVObject is each chart in that sheet.

Comment: @Karen, what is the expected output? It is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: try: `var type = QVObject.GetType(); var myString = type.Namespace;` (from working code I'm looking at...)

Comment: It is not clear why you would want to convert the object to a string. Wouldn't the object here be something like a chart/listbox/etc.? What do you want the string to be then?

Comment: @NamelessOne I have a Qlik View charts. I am copying those charts to word document. I have a text box which has name of the user on whom other charts are related. This name is several times on the document. I want to store this text box value in global variable so that i can just replace it in whole word document.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with COM objects, but my understanding is that they are objects managed by a different process, in this case a QlikView process. You might be able to convert the object into its 'real' type and then interact with the object in the same way as QlikView does. Once you can do this, reading out the text will be easy. But as I say, this is outside my expertise. If I were you, I would read up on using COM objects in C#, because the conversion that I have in mind is more intricate than a simple cast and might have limitations that I am not aware of.

Comment: @NamelessOne you are correct. I am able to copy the chart to work document using  QVObject.CopyTextToClipboard();. Instead i want to store it in string.

Comment: Suppose text box has value Alex. I am able to copy it to word. I want it to be stored in global variable string.

Comment: `Clipboard.GetText()` returns a string, although this is a bit of a hack

Comment: @NamelessOne Thank you so much . It worked. IF you put that in answer i will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments)

Calling `QVObject.CopyTextToClipboard();` get the text from the object to the clipboard, which can then be retrieved by calling `Clipboard.GetText();`.

The downside of this is that it destroys what was on the clipboard before your code ran. But it at least uses QlikView's existing text retrieval to get the contents of the object.